# What is the link to new material on Se-C?

Tags: support

I was given a link to see what new activity was occurring on SE-C : new questions and new answers to old questions. But I had to re-install my browser and I lost the bookmarked link.

Can anyone assist ?

Answer (score 2):

On any StackExchange site, there is a different menu when you click "Questions" on the left nav bar.

[image]

then you can see the newest questions

[image]

Comment: I was after the link which shows 'recent activity' - both new questions _and also new answers_.

Comment: @nigel I think I found it and duped your question to the original one

Comment: Thank you. Appreciated.